# RediSearch - see full query in error logs

Tags: logging, redis, redisearch

I sometimes see errors like `Error parsing query: Syntax error at offset 1 near 'x'` in logs and unsure if there's any way to see the actual query in logs? There doesn't seem to be any way to configure this at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current version (1.4.0), RediSearch does not provide this functionality. Please feel free to suggest it as a feature request at its repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `redis-cli` with the `monitor` option to see the queries being executed. It's not exactly what you want but it can help you.

```
$ redis-cli -h <host-name> -p <port-name> monitor
```

In the same terminal window, you'll be able to see the queries being executed.

**You can `grep` over the output if you know what your *erroneous* query contains.**

For example:

```
$ redis-cli -h <host-name> -p <port-name> monitor | grep -i "GET x"
```

Refer: https://redis.io/commands/MONITOR